# Javascript Variable assignment from remote text file

Tags: javascript, file

I am having an html file with javascript code. I am having a variable like

```
 var testData={
        max: 27,
        data: [ {lat: 20.7300, lng: 81.2000, count: 5},     
                {lat: 21.6700, lng: 82.1700, count: 7},     
                {lat: 23.7579 , lng:83.6866, count: 2},     
                {lat: 19.0667, lng: 82.0331, count: 10},    
                {lat: 21.7197 , lng:81.5375, count: 6},     
                {lat: 18.8000 , lng:80.8166, count: 5},     
                {lat: 22.0900 , lng:82.1500, count: 60},    
                {lat: 18.9000 , lng:81.3500, count: 4},     
                {lat: 20.7072 , lng:81.5497, count: 9},     
                {lat: 21.1833 , lng:81.2833, count: 7},     
                {lat: 20.6330 , lng:82.0623, count: 3},     
                {lat: 22.9000 , lng:84.1500, count: 3},     
                {lat: 22.0170 , lng:82.5670, count: 80},    
                {lat: 19.6000 , lng:81.6700, count: 7},     
                {lat: 22.3500 , lng:82.6800, count: 8},     
                {lat: 23.2500 , lng:82.5500, count: 8},     
                {lat: 20.2719 , lng:81.4931, count: 10},    
                {lat: 22.0200 , lng:81.2500, count: 3},     
                {lat: 21.1000 , lng:82.1000, count: 0},     
                {lat: 22.0700 , lng:81.6800, count: 9},     
                {lat: 19.7149 , lng:81.2455, count: 2},     
                {lat: 21.9000 , lng:83.4000, count: 3},     
                {lat: 21.1000 , lng:81.0300, count: 5},     
                {lat: 21.2447 , lng:81.6352, count: 100},   
                {lat: 23.2200 , lng:82.8500, count: 1},     
                {lat: 18.4000 , lng:81.6667, count: 8},     
                {lat: 23.1167 , lng:83.2000, count: 0 }]    
    };
```

I want to get the value of this variable from a remote text file like data.txt and use it. Please guide me how to achieve this.

After your responses I tried this

```
var testData
$.ajax({
 dataType: "json",
 url: 'data.txt',
 success: function(json_data)
   {
      testData = JSON.parse(json_data);
   }});
```

I have stored my data in the same directory. I am not getting the desired result please help.

Comment: Is the remote file accessible via the web?

Comment: What format is the text file?

Comment: What is the character encoding the file?

Comment: Can you reformat the text file?

Comment: comment out the line that starts with "testData..." and add this: console.log(json_data)  then look at the console and see what it says.

Answer (score 1):

You need these steps:

- Save the data to a text file (without variable name), i.e. the text file would contain:

```
    {
        max: 27,
        data: [ {lat: 20.7300, lng: 81.2000, count: 5},     
            {lat: 21.6700, lng: 82.1700, count: 7},
    ....
    }
```

- Copy the text file to the remote server.
- From JavaScript, make an AJAX call with `$.get()` function to get the contents of the file and parse it with `JSON.parse()` function.

Comment: Hi Ahmed I have edited the question, How I am doing it. Its now working.

Comment: As you are using dataType: "json", you don't need JSON.parse(). json_data is the object you need to access directly.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery [Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) method,If your file contain value in Json format

```
   $.ajax({
     dataType: "json",
     url: 'path_to/data.txt',
     success: function(json_data)
       {
          //json_data contain text file content
       }
   });
```

Comment: It's not valid json, so what now?  eval?

Comment: @BrianMcGinity,What type content?

Comment: @shijn huh?  I am just saying his file is not valid json. So once it was brought into the success function, what would you do?  It looks like the only thing you could do with the data at that point to make it a js variable is to eval() it, which is just a bad idea all around.  So unless he could change his .txt file, there are not very good options.

Comment: @BrianMcGinity I tried eval also. its not working. I used data type as text.